# The simpliest example of overriding methods with generics

Tags: java, generics

I've read all the information, but still can't find the reason why in this basic example overriding is not possible. Please, explain.

```
class Fruit{}
class Apple extends Fruit{}

class Parent {
    public Set<Fruit> getIt(){
     return null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    public Set<Apple> getIt(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is not overriding. What you want is called covariance. That means that you want to use as the return type `Set<Apple>` of the overriding method of a subclass `Child` a subtype of the return type of original method `Set<Fruit>`of the class `Parent`.

But, alas, `Set<Apple>` is not a subtype of `Set<Fruit>` in Java, even if `Apple` is a subtype of `Fruit`. For a very simple reason: you can add any `Fruit` to a `Set<Fruit>`, if `Set<Apple>` were a `Set<Fruit>` then you would be able to add a `Banana` to a `Set<Apple>` as anything possible in a super class is possible in a subclass...

So `Set<Fruit>` and `Set<Apple>` are unrelated types, and this forbids overriding.

Comment: Just to make it complete. The arrays are Co-variant. So this code should work just fine.                                                                                                 class Fruit{}
  class Apple extends Fruit{}

  class Parent {
    public Fruit[] getIt(){
   return null;
    }
  }

  class Child extends Parent {
    @Override // THIS WILL WORK
    public Apple[] getIt(){
   return null;
    }
  }

Comment: Sure. Of course any attempt to violate the type in array covariance will throw an exception. Array covariance type safety is enforced at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of the overriding method must be a sub-type of the return type of the overridden method. `Apple` may be a sub-type of `Fruit`, but Java generics are invariant in the type parameters, so that does not mean that `Set<Apple>` is a sub-type of `Set<Fruit>`.

Otherwise you could do things like:

```
Parent p = new Child();
Set<Fruit> fruitSet = p.getIt(); // actually a Set<Apple>
fruitSet.add(new Fruit());       // oops!
```

You can fix this by using type bounds:

```
class Parent {
    public Set<? extends Fruit> getIt() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public Set<Apple> getIt(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Fruit{}
class Apple extends Fruit{}

class Parent {
    public Set<? extends Fruit> getIt(){
        return null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    public Set<Apple> getIt(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

but because a class is not a subclass of itself its better to make fruit to subclass an other class (like SuperFruit) and use it instead of Fruit in your parent `getIt()` method

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding some explanation of what you're doing here.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle by this keyword <? extends Class> your return type accept everything that extends your Class!you need it because when you override a method you cant change the return type

Comment: I know what `<? extends Class>` means, but I guess the OP doesn't. That's why I asked you to add explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem to your answer.